# How clear footer of jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I tried this but its clearing whole grid data.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("clearGridData","clearfooter", false,true);
```

I want to clear only footer data.

Comment: It will always clear the contents when using this method, the option `clearfooter` is optionally provided to clear the footer too along with the body , and the correct syntax is `$("#grid").jqGrid.clearGridData(true)`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The correct code is:

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-ftable td", "#jqGridId_gbox").html("&#160;");
```

Where the jqGridId is the id of the grid

Sorry for the mistake

Comment: @RupeshBhivgade Have updated the code. Please look at it